# How do you separate parallax elements from header?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have moving parallax elements overlaying a large header image, however I can't seem to figure out how to separate the two so that the header image isn't affected by the parallax movement.

I'd like for only the circles to be moving upwards as you scroll, but it looks like the header image is attached to the same movement as the black circle.

Something I've tried was taking

```
<div class="background">...</div>
```

outside of

```
<div class="parallax">...</div>
```

but then the circles were no longer overlaying the header image.

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uk0x33mj/3/

Thank you - I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you explain what you want more clearly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but what I want is for the header to not move at all when scrolling. It's a little hard to tell, but it moves the same exact way as the black circle (it looks stuck to the header), and I couldn't figure out how to separate the parallax elements which should only be the circles from the header. So how it should look is that the black circle moves upwards and eventually covers part of the header text, rather than staying static with the header. Thanks!

Comment: you mean, header should be position: fixed?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you need something like that. Please let me know, if you need something else.

```css
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:9999;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.circle {
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:300px;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.circle_2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:300px;
}

.background {
  background:red;
  background-image: url('http://i59.tinypic.com/2eofekz.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.spacer {
  height:1000px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  </div>

<div class="parallax">
    
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <svg class="circle_2" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="576px" height="576px" viewBox="0 0 576 576" enable-background="new 0 0 576 576" xml:space="preserve">
        <circle fill="#EC008C" cx="63.215" cy="61.778" r="41.83"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <svg class="circle" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        width="576px" height="576px" viewBox="0 0 576 576" enable-background="new 0 0 576 576" xml:space="preserve">
        <circle fill="#231F20" cx="63.215" cy="61.778" r="41.83"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
      
  <div class="spacer"></div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Setting a fixed background image doesn't seem to work. It looks like there are two scrollbars now because of the parallax elements. I've drawn up a more complete idea of what I want to achieve - I hope it's helpful in some way. http://i59.tinypic.com/10clz6r.jpg This is a website layout, and when you scroll, only the circles should move. By adding the fixed background, it made it so that the white content area overlapped the header image as well, but I want it to stay relative. Thanks so much again for the help!